# Sorting a word into alphabetical order in c

Tags: c, sorting

Trying to use a bubble sort to put a word into alphabetical order. can anyone find the error in my code, I am calling it but it doesn't seem to be doing what it should

```
void alphasort(char *word, int length)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i<length-1; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<length-i-1; ++j)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j+1])
            {
                k= array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = k;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

It simply returns the original word

Comment: Your parameter is called  `word` and the code refers to (the global?) `array`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the logic you are using.

The only fault is, you have an undefined variable, `array`. Either replace all the `array` instances with `word`, or change `char *word` to `char *array`.

Code:

```
void alphasort(char *array, int length)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for(i=0; i<length-1; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<length-i-1; ++j)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j+1])
            {
                k= array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = k;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the variable `array`. Try this instead:

```
void alphasort(char *word, int length)
    {
        int i, j, k;
        for(i=0; i<length-1; ++i)
        {
            for(j=0; j<length-i-1; ++j)
            {
                if (word[j] > word[j+1])
                {
                    k= word[j];
                    word[j] = word[j+1];
                    word[j+1] = k;
                }
            }
         }
    }
```